# _objc_empty_vtable The file "..." couldn't be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, nsarray, objective-c-blocks, nssortdescriptor

this is a self answering question. Putting it out there to help others.

I just had a really interesting crash with my app. What I wanted to do was to define a sort comparator that would be returned a static method in the model.

So, for example if my model is Car, and I want to sort by name, I would have in `Car.m`:

```
+ (NSComparator)nameSortAscendingComparator {
    NSComparator nameSortAscendingComparator = ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSString *a = [(Car *)obj1 name];
        NSString *b = [(Car *)obj2 name] ;
        return [a compare:b] ;
    };
}
```

The invoking code looks something like this:

```
    NSComparator comparator = [Car nameSortAscendingComparator];
   _sortedCars = [cars sortedArrayUsingComparator:comparator];
```

Running this gave a real red herring exception. In fact, it looked something like this:

[image: Xcode's main debug window screenshot]

With the breakpoint stopped on:

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x0231fcbc in _objc_empty_vtable ()
#1  0x0280c70a in __56-[NSArray sortedArrayFromRange:options:usingComparator:]_block_invoke_0 ()
#2  0x0273f07d in __CFSimpleMergeSort ()
#3  0x0273f124 in __CFSimpleMergeSort ()
#4  0x0273f008 in CFSortIndexes ()
#5  0x0277ad71 in -[NSArray sortedArrayFromRange:options:usingComparator:] ()
#6  0x0279a2b5 in -[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:] ()
```

It led me up all sorts of garden paths. Could a block not be accessed as a static variable, or via a static method? Possibly it was doing all this in the `initialize` that was causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The give away was a compiler warning I failed to spot. As always, allowing compiler warnings to accumulate can be deadly. They obscure a real problem when it occurs.

In this case, it was:

```
Control reaches end of non-void function
```

Yep, my `nameSortAscendingComparator` method didn't actually return anything. Doh! Problem solved.

What I'd be curious about, would be the explanation behind the obscure "no such file" message? Not to mention the _objc_empty_vtable. I'd love to know more about the vtable, and it's relationship to the non-void function crash.